# A misunderstanding of how this javascript is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bind an event to a channel on the client side that waits for a message from the server and triggers the anonymous function in a callback, passing the message data in the `thing` parameter.

```
channel.bind('coordinates_sent', function(thing) {
     var x = thing.left;
     var y = thing.top;

     $(window).scroll(function(){
           alert(x + " " + y);
     });

     alert(x + " " + y);
});
```

The alert message outside of the `scroll` method works as expected. It alerts the new x and y coordinates of the data sent from the server right when the new message arrives.

However, the alert message inside the scroll message behaves differently from how I would expect it to. If one message has been sent to the event listener, then the alert correctly displays the x and y coordinates from that message every time I scroll. However, if another message comes in, the alert displays first the original x and y coordinates from the first message, and then a separate alert displays the x and y coordinates from the most recent message.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're receiving a message from the server, you're attaching a new `scroll` event handler. When you attach an event listener, existing listeners are *not* removed. When the user scrolls, all attached event handlers are executed.

To fix this, move the part where it attaches a `scroll` event outside of the event handler for a message being received by the server:

```
var x, y;
channel.bind('coordinates_sent', function(thing) {
    x = thing.left;
    y = thing.top;

    alert(x + " " + y);
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    alert(x + " " + y);
});
```

Comment: aren't `x` and `y` scoped locally inside the anonymous function?

Comment: @Justin: Oh, good point. What are you attempting to achieve? When the user scrolls, display the last coordinates received from the server?

Comment: yeah exactly, maybe if the `scroll` event handler is inside the callback but first remove all `scroll` event handlers if there is a way to do that?

Comment: @Justin: If you kept a reference to the last one that could work (you'd use `unbind`), but if you look at my updated answer, I think that might be simpler.

Comment: that would do it, but I don't want to pollute the global namespace. Maybe if you wrapped all of that in a self-invoking function, but that code might get messy

Comment: @Justin: You could wrap it in a self-executing anonymous function: `!function(){ var x, y; /* ... */ }();`

Comment: @Justin: You could also put it in an object. Somewhere: `var lastCoords;` In the server handler: `lastCoords = {x: thing.left, y: thing.top};` In the `scroll` handler: `alert(lastCoords.x + " " + lastCoords.y);`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .bind() method registers handlers but doesnt unbound them. Try to use .one() instead, see [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/).